# Implicit grammar in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-と, quotes

Sentence in question:
万が一、事故に巻き込まれたりしたら、確実に勝ち目はないだろうなぁと、いつも不安になった。

For full context:
https://www.satorireader.com/articles/sanzu-no-kawa-episode-1-edition-m?sentenceID=SrOvSLFfSOyCJFzmEmFt

My attempt at translation:
"I was (=became?) anxious  that in the unlikely event that I would have gotten involved into an accident, I wouldn't have a chance."

First, I'm not sure why たり is used here. Usually I see たり when multiple examples are given, but here it is only one thing. I guess it is because the speaker wants to express that this is just one of the (bad) things that could've happened?

Second, the usage of と. Thanks to the aids provided SatoriReader, I could check for the function of と here myself. I usually encountered と in the quotative function only when followed by a verb expressing thought (e.g. 思う) or speech (e.g. 言う). In this case, the thought is kind of indicated by だろう. However, I wanted to ask wether this is a common phenomenon in japanese, that thought or speech isn't explicitely indicated through the respective verbs when と is used in a quotative function.

Comment: Related (the usage of と): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45089/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24583/9831

Comment: Related (たり): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52658/5010

Answer (score 1):

Two resources were kindly introduced in the comment. I adopt this method:
[Use of quote marker と before unusual verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24583/use-of-quote-marker-%E3%81%A8-before-unusual-verbs). It explains you can use an italic font for a quotation. So, you might try to express "確実に勝ち目はないだろうなぁと" using an italic font in English writing.

Probably going like this, "If I were to get involved in the accident, *it's pretty sure that I could not win*, I was getting nervous like that".

As for "たり", in the following sentence, other good things for having a small vehicle are explicitly stated "燃費もいいし、駐車するのも楽だから". I think your guess is correct for "たり".