# Can you omit the action when using と and help understanding/parsing this sentence

Tags: particle-と, parsing

> 『監視されているみたいだ』と不評の声も多い見回りだけど, 案外さっきみたいな事柄のためにやっているのかもしれないな。

The complete sentence is given above. As the title has said, can you omit the action when using と? From some sentences I've seen, an action verb often accompanies と when used with direct quotes. I am aware of って being used as a casual quoting particle where we can omit other parts of the sentence but can that also be applied for と when used with direct quotes?

If that is so then, would it go『監視されているみたいだ』という不評の声... and mean something like

> "The numerous watchmen are also like the (unpopular) voices saying 'It seems like we're being watched' but/and..."

Like a simile/metaphor? My attempt at translation would then be (not that it makes much sense)

> "The numerous watchmen are also like the (unpopular) voices saying 'It seems like we're being watched' and It might be because of unexpected things like earlier happening."

Maybe I'm misinterpreting the と？ I haven't had much experience with sentences like this and even with context I could barely understand the statement. This sentence is probably way above what my current abilities are capable of understanding and that any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

For some context, the previous scene was showing the student council doing their routine patrol when they stumbled upon an incident involving the speaker and the current scene is a narration.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24583/7810

Comment: I see. So the action can be omitted even in direct quotations. So was I right in thinking that this sentence is, for example, similar to sentences like "I was about to go outside but it suddenly rained and **it was like God was telling me 'Don't go'**? If it isn't how would one go about saying that in Japanese?

Comment: Specifically to the sentence you give, you can let *rain* say "don't go" but not *God* in your sentence with this pattern.

Comment: Trying to follow the sentence structure above. Would 「いくな」という声も雨だった mean "The rain was also (like) a voice telling me 'Don't go'"?

Answer (score 1):

I think your comprehension of 「と」 is correct.

> 『監視されているみたいだ』と不評の声
>
> 『監視されているみたいだ』という不評の声

These 2 phrases are basically the same as you inferred.

The tree of this sentence is like below.

> NPだけど, 案外さっきみたいな事柄のためにやっているのかもしれないな。
>
> (NP = Noun Phrase)

Here, "NPだけど" means "Regarding NP", "As for NP", or something like that. To make clear we often use "NP**について**だけど、", "NP**に関して**だけど" but sometimes they are omitted. Thus you could translate this like "Regarding NP, it might be because of unexpected things like earlier happening."

The NP in this sentence is "『監視されているみたいだ』と不評の声も多い見回り". And the head of this NP is "見回り"(watchmen) as you assembled. But you missed another point!! 多い is modifying "不評の声" here, not watchmen!! "-の声も多い" is kind of phrase meaning "It is frequently said as -".

Thus the whole translation is like this.

> Regarding watchmen who are often blamed as "It seems like we're being watched",  it might be for the things like the earlier happening, against my expect.

Comment: Thanks, I mostly assumed that adjectives could only modify what is next to them. With regards to the omission of について/に関して, if they aren't omitted do we still need to use だ before けど or is that like a set expression? I am going by the assumption that the だけど is the same to だが meaning "but".

Comment: Yes!! As you said, だ is still required after について/に関して. I think this だ is omitted only in case of verb phrase like "電話したけど". And your last assumption is correct too. だけど is functionally the same as だが as well as けど is the same as が. So actually だ and けど are different components.

Comment: On top of this, `I mostly assumed that adjectives could only modify what is next to them.` sorry for making confused but this is basically correct!! In the sentence, "不評の声も多い" modifies "見回り", along with the basic rule. This is not an exception.